# Why does `Get-ChildItem` require a call to `invoke-sqlcmd` to see `SQL SERVER:\SQL\...`?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

PowerShell has a cool module for [interacting with SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/sql-server-powershell?view=sql-server-ver16&viewFallbackFrom=sqlserver-ps). One of the [features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/sql-server-identifiers-in-powershell?view=sql-server-ver16) is the ability to navigate database objects like file system objects. For example:

```
get-childitem -Path "SQLSERVER:\SQL\MSI\DEFAULT\DATABASES"
```

However, instead of a list of objects, I get the following error message:

```
get-childitem : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'SQLSERVER' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-childitem -Path "SQLSERVER:\SQL\"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SQLSERVER:String) [Get-ChildItem], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

After spending a few hours and acquiring a few gray hairs, I accidentally discovered that it is possible to get it to work if at least once to make the following a call:

```
invoke-sqlcmd
```

Then `get-childitem` sees the `SQLSERVER` disk and returns me a list of tables. Beauty :-)

---

Obviously, calling `invoke-sqlcmd` changes something in the environment that allows `get-childitem` to interact with `SQLSERVER`. However, [neither in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/sql-server-identifiers-in-powershell?view=sql-server-ver16) nor in the examples on the Internet, I did not find anything about this, which makes me think that the problem is in my system. What did I miss? Did they just forget to mention it in the documentation? Or is it not a bug but a feature, and `invoke-sqlcmd` performs authorization?

*I used windows authorization in tests*

*OS: Windows 10 Enterprise and Windows Server 2019*

*SQL Server version: 15.0.2000.5 developer edition*

Comment: Sounds like a missing module which needs to be loaded first

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows 10 & SQL Server 2019 (although I've no reason to believe it's limited to those versions). I have yet to find a solution, though invoke-sqlcmd solves it in the short-term. I think Charlieface is right about the missing module but I didn't see any errors when I ran through my setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're seeing is the [module auto-loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/importing-a-powershell-module?view=powershell-7.3#implicitly-importing-a-module-powershell-30) which exists in PowerShell 3+. The `SQLSERVER` module is not loaded into your session (so the `PSDrive` doesn't exist) until you execute one or more functions from that module.

You can explicitly load the module with `import-module sqlserver` in your session/script prior to using the `SQLServer` drive and it will be available from that point forward.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the reason is related to module auto-loading. Thank you! If  execute `import-module sqlPS` then everything works (during tests, I found that it turns out I use the `sqlPS` module instead of `SqlServer`)

Comment: @Ivan please don't use the `sqlps` module. It was obsoleted in 2016 or 2017 when the `sqlserver` module was released.